# Different accuracy on google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I have this CNN:

```
def cnn(trainImages, trainLabels, testImages, testLabels):
    trainImages = np.array(trainImages)
    trainLabels = np.array(trainLabels)
    testImages = np.array(testImages)
    testLabels = np.array(testLabels)

    trainImages = trainImages / 255
    testImages = testImages / 255

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu', input_shape = (224, 224, 3)))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = (3, 3), padding = 'same', activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2), strides = (2, 2)))

    model.add(Flatten())

    model.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(9))

    opt = Adam(learning_rate = 0.001)

    model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = tensorflow.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits = True), metrics = ['accuracy'])

    model.fit(trainImages, trainLabels, epochs = 20, batch_size = 64)

    predictionResult = model.predict(testImages)

    pred = []
    for i in range(len(predictionResult)):
        pred.append(np.argmax(predictionResult[i], axis = -1))

    vehicles = ['Black Vehicles', 'Blue Vehicles', 'Brown Vehicles', 'Green Vehicles', 'Pink Vehicles', 'Red Vehicles', 'Silver Vehicles', 'White Vehicles', 'Yellow Vehicles']

    print('Accuracy: ', metrics.accuracy_score(testLabels, pred))

    print(metrics.classification_report(testLabels, pred, target_names = vehicles))

    print(metrics.confusion_matrix(testLabels, pred))
```

On local I got 93%, but in Google Colab only 10%. What happens? I see that on Google Colab first training epochs have a bad accuracy 10-15% and suddenly increase to 35% in one epoch, 60% in second, over 90% in third.

Comment: So, basically at the end both have similar accuracy? If so then what is wrong?

Comment: Accuracy on testing dataset is bad, around 10% on google colab. Accuracy on training epochs its just an observation.

Comment: Training accuracy is low at first maybe due to random weight initialization.
As for the model, try using "validation_data" while fitting the model. And see how it performs on local and colab.

Comment: Considering that everything is kept same from data splits to the hyper-parameters then the only possible difference can come from `random weight initialization` as pointed by @user3503711 but the ending accuracy being only 10% on test set on colab and 90% on local is indeed strange as the difference is usually small.

Comment: I printed all prediction on local and they are good, its not a bug. I tried a svm and its same problem, 86% on local, around 13% on google colab.

Answer (score 0):

You must use activation function- 'Softmax'(for muliclass probabilities) in final layer of the model.

model.add(Dense(9), activation='softmax'))

This will increase the accuracy of the model.

Comment: Just 11%, and I got this warning: ```UserWarning: "`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` received `from_logits=True`, but the `output` argument was produced by a sigmoid or softmax activation and thus does not represent logits. Was this intended?"
  '"`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` received `from_logits=True```